# SortedList<TKey,TValue> and duplicated keys

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, generics, collections

I'm using the [SortedList<TKey, TValue>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2) collection. I find myself frequently doing:

```
if (!sortedList.ContainsKey(key))
{
    sortedList.Add(key, value);
}
```

just to avoid the "duplicated key" exception. I don't like this and the code readability is penalized. I don't need duplicated keys, obviously.

Is there any option or different collection type that helps to skip this check?

Comment: You can create an extension method and wrap the logic in there. And call the extension method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough doing

```cs
sortedList[key] = value;
```

If the key exists, it will be substituted, if it does not, will be created. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: What if op wants to retain old key, value pair if key is already present ?

Comment: That's not what OP asked for

Comment: @Jasmeet has a point that this code does not produce the same behavior as the original code (the code in the question leaves the original value if it exists), but you described the change well in this answer.

Comment: @RufusL Right. With that in mind, your solution is much better and more adequate

Comment: Only if the OP cares about preserving an existing value. If not, your answer is the best. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to retain the old value if the key already exists (which is what your current code does), then checking first is the only option. To simplify things, however, we can create an extension method that wraps the check.

Here's an example that returns a `bool` indicating whether or not the new value was added:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool AddIfMissing<TKey, TValue>(
        this SortedList<TKey, TValue> list, TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        if (list.ContainsKey(key)) return false;
        list.Add(key, value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now when we want to add a value, we don't have to write the code that checks for the key every time, we just write:

```
sortedList.AddIfMissing(key, value);
```